# Using regular expressions in a ksh Script

Tags: regex, unix, ksh

I have a file (file.txt) that contains some text like:

- 000000000+000+0+00
- 000000001+000+0+00
- 000000002+000+0+00

and I am trying to check each line to make sure that it follows the format:
character*9, "+", character*3, "+", etc

so far I have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
file=file.txt
line_number=1
for line in $(cat $file)
do
    if [[ "$line" != "[[.]]{9}+[[.]]{3}+[[.]]{1}+[[.]]{2} ]" ]]
    then
        echo "Invalid number ($line) check line $line_number"
        exit 1
    fi
    let "line_number++"
done
```

however this does not evaluate correctly, no matter what I put in the lines the program terminates.

Comment: This isn't a "Unix script", that's not a thing, it's a `ksh` script.

Comment: Ok thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having funny results putting the regex in the condition directly:

```
$ line='000000000+000+0+00'
$ [[ $line =~ ^.{9}\+.{3}\+.\+..$ ]] && echo ok
ksh: syntax error: `~(E)^.{9}\+.{3}\+.\+..$ ]] && echo ok
' unexpected
```

But if I save the regex in a variable:

```
$ re="^.{9}\+.{3}\+.\+..$"
$ [[ $line =~ $re ]] && echo ok
ok
```

So you can do

```
#!/bin/ksh
file=file.txt
line_number=1
re="^.{9}\+.{3}\+.\+..$"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ ! $line =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "Invalid number ($line) check line $line_number"
        exit 1
    fi
    let "line_number++"
done < "$file"
```

---

You can also use a plain glob pattern:

```
if [[ $line != ?????????+???+?+?? ]]; then echo error; fi
```

---

ksh glob patterns have some regex-like syntax. If there's an *optional* space in there, you can handle that with the `?(sub-pattern)` syntax

```
pattern="?????????+???+?( )?+??"

line1="000000000+000+0+00"
line2="000000000+000+ 0+00"

[[ $line1 == $pattern ]] && echo match || echo no match  # => match
[[ $line2 == $pattern ]] && echo match || echo no match  # => match
```

Read the "File Name Generation" section of the ksh man page.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use the last one. After the second '+' it is possible to have a space as a character, do you know of a way to account for that as well?

Comment: Never mind, the problem was actually that the default IFS is space,tab,or new line. When I changed IFS=$'\n' it now does exactly what I wanted. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

When you want line numbers of the mismatches, you can use `grep -vn`. Be careful with writing a correct regular expression, and you will have

```
grep -Evn "^.{9}[+].{3}[+].[+].{2}$" file.txt
```

This is not in the layout that you want, so change the layout with `sed`:

```
grep -Evn "^.{9}[+].{3}[+].[+].{2}$" file.txt |
   sed -r 's/([^:]*):(.*)/Invalid number (\2) check line number \1./'
```

EDIT:
I changed `.{1}` into `.`.
The `sed` is also over the top. When you need spme explanation, you can start with `echo "Linenr:Invalid line"`

Comment: The `{1}` is obviously superfluous; maybe take it out before someone laughs.

Comment: Teaching users to read `grep -n` output may ultimately be a better strategy than attempting to make it properly human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex looks [bad](https://regex101.com/r/H9Bd0Q/1) - using sites like https://regex101.com/ is *very* helpful. From your description, I suspect it should look more like one of these;

- `^.{9}\+.{3}\+.{1}\+.{2}$`
- `^[^\+]{9}\+[^\+]{3}\+[^\+]{1}\+[^\+]{2}$`
- `^[0-9]{9}\+[0-9]{3}\+[0-9]{1}\+[0-9]{2}$`

---

From the [`ksh` manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html) section on `[[` - you would probably want to be using `=~`.

```
string =~ ere
    True if string matches the pattern ~(E)ere where ere is an extended regular expression.
```

Note: As far as I know, `ksh` regex doesn't follow the normal syntax

---

You may have better luck with using `grep`:

```
# X="000000000+000+0+00"
# grep -qE "^[^\+]{9}\+[^\+]{3}\+[^\+]{1}\+[^\+]{2}$" <<<"${X}" && echo true
true
```

Or:

```sh
if grep -qE "^[^\+]{9}\+[^\+]{3}\+[^\+]{1}\+[^\+]{2}$" <<<"${line}"
then
    exit 1
fi
```

---

You may also prefer to use a construct like below for handling files:

```sh
while read line; do
    echo "${line}";
done < "${file}"
```